# What is the current installation path of Android paid app on device?

Tags: android, google-play, android-5.0-lollipop, android-install-apk

Background: from Android 4.1 Jelly Bean, all installed paid apps are encrypted under /mnt/asec, while others are under /data/app.

Details: http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/08/08/jelly-bean-app-encryption-breaks-thousands-of-apps-in-the-play-store-google-disables-drm-for-now/

Currently when I download paid apps again from Play Store, I find that no app is actually encrypted under /mnt/asec. If I copy the base.apk using "adb pull", I can successfully install it on another phone.

Someone asked a similar question before:

> [What is the current status of Android app encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840473/what-is-the-current-status-of-android-app-encryption)

but there's no clear answer regarding to the installation path.

Is the above mentioned encryption feature dismissed now? When did Google change it?

My device is Nexus 5 running the latest 5.0 Lollipop.

Comment: you should accept the answer provided if it sufficiently answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, they remain on /data/app folder:

[image: /data/app/]

Comment: Thanks for your comment Guillermo. Is this a paid app downloaded from Google Play?

Comment: Does anyone know why there's a "-1" at the end of the package name? (com.pixelbite.rr3-1) I see this in every app I've looked at.

Comment: @Patrick I believe that's belong to per-user user ID when multi-user is introduced. See section "How it’s made in the OS" from https://arsenb.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/android-multiuser-model-architecture-and-related-security-threats/